# how to get the value of cmake defined variables

Tags: cmake

I can get the value of some variables such as: CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR, but why I can't get the value of FLAGS and SOURCES by ${FLAGS} ${SOURCES}? How can I get the values of this two variables?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are these environment variables?

Comment: These variables are defined by cmake itself, as CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR is. The cmake defined variables are list here: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Comment: Is the name of the variable really 'FLAGS'? I think the name is 'CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS'

Comment: Yeah. You can refer to this website. All the cmake defined variables are list here: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Comment: So, what do you really mean?  I'd expect the value of `${FLAGS}` to be empty by default since CMake doesn't define it (it's not a CMake-defined variable).  Can you show us a snippet which explains your problem?

Comment: I assume the OP is using a CMakeLists.txt that defines these variables. And the OP wants to print them. MESSAGE( STATUS ${FLAGS} )